# C++11 thread event : std::future vs std::condition_variable

Tags: multithreading, c++11, promise, condition-variable

I'm writing a network test program.
The idea is to have 2 threads. The client and the server.
I want to add some eventing between the 2 threads.

Basicly

1. Main thread runs the server and creates a new thread for client.
2. Server thread waits for client to connect.
3. Client thread sends some data and notifies the server thread.
4. Client Thread waits.
5. Server reads the data. Checks if data is intact and notifies the client thread to send more data.
6. Repeat a number of times in a loop, but server does not know how many times.
7. After all the data has been send, client thread notifies server thread to exit his loop. Server thread ( main thread joins the client thread. )

I have implemented this using a global std::condition_variable and global variables and it works. I'm writing multiple of these tests functions. Each test function does what I described above but with different data.

Here are some questions that I have:

1. I found std::promise and std::future. I like the fact that it waits for a value to be set in another thread. Could i use this instead of std::condition_variable? In general, what are use cases for using one method over another when waiting for a variable to be set? Differences, advantages/disadvantages?
2. Would it be better to declare the std::condition_variable and the variables locally in each test function and pass references to the thread instead of using global variables? For some reason I don't like using global variables.. What would be a better practice?
3. Do you need to join a thread if you are certain it will end before the main thread? My client thread notifies the server thread ( main thread ) when it is done sending and will exit, So really the server thread is waiting for the client thread to exit. Do i still need to join it in the main thread?

Comment: condition_variable will be more suitable for your example. Use promise - future for thread synchronization and condition_variable for mutual exclusion. You can join the thread in class destructor.